# compositions of n with k even summands and compositions of n-k with k odd summands

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A composition of the number n with k summands is the representation
>   n=a1+⋯+ak
>   with integers ai≥1,1≤i≤k. The order of the summands is important.

Show that: There are as many compositions of n with k even summands as compositions of n-k with k odd summands exist.

Let $a=(a_1,\dots a_k)$ be a composition with $a_i\geq2$ , $1\leq i\leq j$ and $a_1 + \dots a_k=n-2k$

Let $a'=(a'_1,\dots a'_k)$ be a composition with $a'_i=a_i-1,1\leq i\leq j$

$\Rightarrow$ a' has k odd summands

$\Rightarrow a'_1+\dots +a'_k=(a_i-1) + \cdots +(a_i-1)= a_1+\dots+a_k-k=_1 n-3k$

$\Rightarrow$ for each composition $a_1+\dots+a_k=n$ with $a_i$ even there is a k $a'_1+\dots+a_k=n-3k$ with $a_i$ odd.

Now Let $a=(a_1,\dots a_k)$ be a composition with $a_i\geq2$, $1\leq i\leq j$ and $a_1 + \dots a_k=n-3k$

Let $a'=(a'_1,\dots a'_k)$ be a composition with $a'_i=a_i+1,1\leq i\leq j$

$\Rightarrow a'_1+\dots +a'_k=a_1 + \cdots +a_k+k= n-2k$ with k even summands

and that es right ?

Thank you

[1] Thanks to @shardulc

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386542/ferrers-diagram-partitions for ideas regarding this.

Comment: @Noah You're welcome! If you accept an answer, please check the green arrow to the left of the answer so that other users know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method you are using (you have almost got it right), for every composition of $n=a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_k$, we subtract $1$ from each $a_i$. So, we get $(a_1-1)+(a_2-1)+\dotsb+(a_k-1) =a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_k  - k = n-k$. Note that we can do this for every composition of $n$ to get a unique composition of $k$: since $a_i > 0$ is even, we can always subtract $1$ to get an odd number, and it is easy to prove (try it!) that all the resulting compositions of $n-k$ are unique.

(The number of compositions are equal because we can construct a composition for one given the other, and vice versa, so there is a 'bijection')

Answer (score 1):

You started OK but I think you should try to do it as follows:

If you starting with $n$ and any $a_i$ is even, and in particular $a_i\geq 2$, you can start by "giving" each $a_i$ $2$.

You are left with the problem of non-negative even (any $a_i$ is even) solotions of (you already gave $2k$)
$$a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_k=n-2k.$$

Show that the other problem correspond to the same problem.

Comment: i have edited it. i hope i understand what you mean